# Animation won't start

Tags: android

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong.  I create an animation, load it with 50 frames.  Attempt to start it, but nothing happens.  The initial start frame is there, but nothing happens.  I printed the amount of frames the animation object has, and it says 50.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ShowCircle(50);
}
public void ShowCircle(final int percentage){

        final ImageView ring = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ring);

        animation = new AnimationDrawable();
        ring.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                for(int i = 0; i != percentage; i++){
                    try
                    {           
                        final int id = R.drawable.class.getField("rings_" + i).getInt(0);
                        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(id), 100);
                    }
                    catch(NoSuchFieldException n)
                    {
                        MessageBox(n.toString());
                    }
                    catch(IllegalAccessException e)
                    {
                        MessageBox(e.toString());
                    }
                }
                animation.setOneShot(false);
                ring.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
                ring.post(new Starter());
                MessageBox("# of frames: " + Integer.toString(animation.getNumberOfFrames()));
            }
        });
    }

    class Starter implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            animation.start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, stupid me, there was a default image for the ImageView.  The animated image was only set to the background, and that's why it was never visible...